# How to implement OptionFlag with urfave/cli

Tags: go, command-line-interface

Is there a way to define an OptionFlag with `urfave/cli`?

I'm looking for something that will look like this.

```
mycli --format json
mycli --format xml
```

I know I can use the StringFlag, but it would be great if I could have the `--help` show what are the valid options/values for this flag, so it is transparent for the end-user of `mycli`.

This way the Flag could also be validated against the options to inform the user he has provided an invalid value for this flag for example, Which ofcourse can also be done with the StringFlag, but would rather have something more sofisticated that does all of this.

I also filed an issue on the Github repository. Maybe it is a missing feature, which I would be happy to contribute with some guidance.

https://github.com/urfave/cli/issues/1154

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `StringSliceFlag` It allows you to define valid/default values for a flag.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/urfave/cli/v2"
)

func main() {

    validMeetings := []string{"standup", "postmortem", "jourfix"}
    meetings := cli.NewStringSlice(validMeetings...)

    app := &cli.App{
        Flags: []cli.Flag{
            &cli.StringSliceFlag{
             Value: meetings,
             Name: "meeting",
             Usage: "use one of the default values"},
        },
        Action: func(c *cli.Context) error {

            m := c.StringSlice("meeting")
            ok := false
            for _, selected := range m {
                for _, valid := range validMeetings {
                    if selected == valid {
                        ok = true
                    }
                }
            }
            if !ok {
                return fmt.Errorf("you must use one of %v", validMeetings)
            }

            fmt.Printf("%s\n", c.String("meeting"))
            return nil
        },
    }

    err := app.Run(os.Args)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/urfave/cli/blob/4f74020d9f07911f0fdb8facbc1f557a12cd2a93/app_test.go#L760

Comment: That would also allow to specify the option multiple times. So like `mycli --meeting standup --meeting jourfix` which is not what I want.